# Binary classification: how to transform features in real numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, algorithms, naive-bayes-classifier

I want to train a binary classification algorithm for spam detection using labeled data set. The dataset has the following features:

```
Email address, text message (split into subject and corpus), date
```

An example of data is:

```
Email | Subject | Corpus | Date 
Gg12_school@gmail.com | Example | this is just an example of my dataset  | 2020/08/20
```

What I would like is to transform data features in real numbers and binarize email addresses.
As algorithm I was thinking of
SVM and/or Naïve Bayes.

My difficulties are, however, in how transform data features in real numbers in order to get more parameters in my classifier.

I am using Python.

Could you please give me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is text classification. There exists a huge number of tutorials and papers out there, for example [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/)  and [this survey](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiqrd6x9anrAhXJ_KQKHfOEAHMQFjALegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgooa.las.ac.cn%2Fexternal%2Fdownload%2F964669%2F3290610%2F20140821184826871.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Hf3sDRVfZEFvni0g2Eod-).